# How to create custom eslint rule for typescript type argument to certain functions

Tags: typescript, eslint

I would like to require type arguments be passed to certain functions in my typescript / react application (although I think this problem is independent of React I am using a react-hook-form context hook as an example).

For example this is allowed and does not give an eslint error.

```
const form = useFormContext();
```

However this example includes the type argument and gives substantial type safety

```
const form = useFormContext<MyFormType>();
```

My question is, how can write a custom eslint rule to enforce certain functions must have type arguments (like `useFormContext` in this example)?

Comment: You don't need eslint in this case. The problem is that you want a stricter function signature than what is provided by the package: the upstream function uses a default generic parameter, so you'll have to send a PR to modify that (seems unlikely to be merged IMO), or you could make your function and re-export it for use in your own code: [example](https://tsplay.dev/WP15Lw). Does that answer your question? If so, I can write it up as one. If not, what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still figuring this out myself, but I have a working solution using `eslint-local-rules` and `eslint-typescript`, that I'm sharing in case it's useful:

In `eslint-local-rules.js`:

```js
const { ESLintUtils } = require('@typescript-eslint/utils')

module.exports = {
  'rhf-require-types': {
    meta: {
      docs: {
        description: 'useFormContext must have type',
      },
      schema: [],
    },
    create(context) {
      const services = ESLintUtils.getParserServices(context)

      return {
        CallExpression(node) {
          const { callee } = node

          // These are the types we expect a type argument for
          const typesExpected = [
            'useForm',
            'useFormContext',
          ]

          if (!typesExpected.includes(callee.name)) return null

          const tsNode = services.esTreeNodeToTSNodeMap.get(node)

          if (!tsNode.typeArguments) {
            context.report({
              node: callee,
              message: `${callee.name} should have a type argument`,
            })
          }

          return null
        },
      }
    },
  },
}
```

And then add `'local-rules/rhf-require-types': 'warn'` to your `.eslintrc`.